# возврат данных в формате JSON

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

Я новичок в работе с json и dto.
Подскажите как вернуть json ответ на страницу браузера?(ИСпользуя RestService)

В ответе получить все взаимосвязыанные профессии и предметы.
У меня имеются связные таблицы Многие-ко-многим в связи с этим я работаю с прослойкой dto

Profession

```
public class ProfessionDto {
@JsonProperty("id")
private int id;

@JsonProperty("SubjectName")
private String professionName;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getProfessionName() {
    return professionName;
}

public void setProfessionName(String professionName) {
    this.professionName = professionName;
}

public static ProfessionWithSubjectDto fromModel(Profession profession){
    ProfessionWithSubjectDto dto =new ProfessionWithSubjectDto();
    dto.setId(profession.getId());
    dto.setProfessionName(profession.getProfessionName());
    List<SubjectDto> subjectDtos = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Subject subject : profession.getSubjects()){
        subjectDtos.add(SubjectDto.fromModel(subject));

    }
    dto.setSubjects(subjectDtos);
    return dto;
```

}
}

Subjects

```
  Public class SubjectDto {
   @JsonProperty("id")
   private Integer id;;

    @JsonProperty("SubjectName")
    private String subjectName;


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSubjectName() {
    return subjectName;
}

public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
    this.subjectName = subjectName;
}

public static SubjectDto fromModel(Subject subject){
    SubjectDto dto = new SubjectDto();
    dto.setId(subject.getId());
    dto.setSubjectName(subject.getSubjectName());
    return dto;
}
```

}

У subject может быть несколько Profession

```
public class ProfessionWithSubjectDto extends ProfessionDto {
@JsonProperty("id")
private int id;
@JsonProperty("professionName")
private String professionName;
@JsonProperty("subjects")
private List<SubjectDto> subjects;

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getProfessionName() {
    return professionName;
}

public void setProfessionName(String professionName) {
    this.professionName = professionName;
}

public List<SubjectDto> getSubjects() {
    return subjects;
}

public void setSubjects(List<SubjectDto> subjectDtos) {
    this.subjects = subjectDtos;
}

public static ProfessionWithSubjectDto fromModel(Profession profession){
    ProfessionWithSubjectDto dto = new ProfessionWithSubjectDto();
    dto.setId(profession.getId());
    dto.setProfessionName(profession.getProfessionName());
    List<SubjectDto> subjectDtos = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Subject subject : profession.getSubjects()){
        subjectDtos.add(SubjectDto.fromModel(subject));
    }
    dto.setSubjects(subjectDtos);

    return dto;
}
```

}

У profession может быть несколько subject

```
public class SubjectWithProfessionDto {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("SubjectName")
    private String SubjectName;
    @JsonProperty("professions")
    private List<ProfessionDto> professions;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubjectName() {
        return SubjectName;
    }

    public void setSubjectName(String subjectName) {
        SubjectName = subjectName;
    }

    public List<ProfessionDto> getProfessions() {
        return professions;
    }
public void setProfessions(List<ProfessionDto> professions) {
    this.professions = professions;
}


public static SubjectWithProfessionDto fromModel (Subject subject){
    SubjectWithProfessionDto dto = new SubjectWithProfessionDto();
    dto.setId(subject.getId());
    dto.setSubjectName(subject.getSubjectName());
    List<ProfessionDto> professionDtos = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Profession profession : subject.getProfessions()){
        professionDtos.add(ProfessionDto.fromModel(profession));

    }

    dto.setProfessions(professionDtos);
    return dto;

}
```

}

Есть прослойка Controller

В ней я хочу вернуть данные(JSON) на страницу используя @ResponseBody

Comment: А в чем сложность? Уже привели аннотацию @ResponseBody. Она не работает?

Comment: @enzo Я не знаю как вернуть конкретно dto. Как возвращать dao я понимаю, а вот dto нет.

Comment: @enzo     `@RequestMapping(value = "/me",method = GET)
                            @ResponseBody
    public List<SubjectDto> getAll(){
        List<Subject> subjects = subjectService.getAll();
        List<SubjectDto> subjectDtos = new ArrayList<>(subjects.size());
        subjects.forEach(subject -> subjectDtos.add(convertToDTO(subject)));`
        return subjectDtos;`   но программа ругается на convertToDTO

Comment: Тогда у вас проблема при конвертации объекта в DTO. Причем тут Spring  и JSON? Ваш метод контроллера должен вернуть объект. Spring этот объект сам преобразует в JSON - ему все равно DTO это или любой другой POJO объект. Вам нужно написать юнит-тест для метода `convertToDTO()`и отладить его.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой и грубый способ - взять структуру данных и пропустить через GSON. Полученную строку отдать return'ом, добавив аннотацию `@ResponseBody`.

Подробнее тут: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-requestbody-and-responsebody-demystified.html

и тут: https://github.com/google/gson

Почему не стандартный spring json - у gson шире возможности работы со сложными объектами.

Comment: А как это сделать с JSON??Нужно именно через него сделать

Comment: Подробная инструкция по созданию сервиса, предоставляющего json данные по запросу: http://devcolibri.com/2890

Comment: Если что, при возврате объекта методом с аннотацией `@ResponseBody`, spring автоматически попытается вернуть json представление объекта, если всё настроено как надо (маппинги в web.xml -> <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>, поддержку `@ResponseBody` в mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml).

Comment: Я работаю через аннотации.(@Controller ) и.т.д Вроде все правильно настроено. Без использования xml

Comment: Хорошо. Возникают какие-то ошибки при попытке вернуть dto?
Вот ещё один гайд, конкретно по спрингу и DTO: http://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application. Попробуйте пройти по нему в тестовом приложении.

Comment: Да.возникают. `@RequestMapping(value = "/me",method = GET) @ResponseBody public List<SubjectDto> getAll(){ List<Subject> subjects = subjectService.getAll(); List<SubjectDto> subjectDtos = new ArrayList<>(subjects.size()); subjects.forEach(subject -> subjectDtos.add(convertToDTO(subject))); return subjectDtos;` `но программа ругается на convertToDTO как будто не понимает, что это за метод

Comment: convertToDTO где объявлен? Я что-то не вижу его в представленных листингах.

Comment: Да, вы правы он действительно не определен.